# How to find values that are not dates in Excel (cleaning data)

Tags: excel

Lets say for example I have a column with dates.

Shown below:

[image]

I want to create a formula in a column/be able to identify the cells in that column that are not in a "standard date" format.

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

=IF(K:K>1,'Error','No Error')

But this doesn't seem to work.

Any pointers would be appreciated :)

Comment: They are all valid dates, just format the column as date format.

Comment: Hi Warcupine, thanks for the response! This is a practice example question for a screening test. And, the test specifically specifies the values are incorrect. Please let me know if there is still a way to solve this issue :)

Comment: I don't think you can through formulas, the only difference between those values is their formatting and I'm not aware of any formulas that deal with that. You would need VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the help, much apprecaited Warcupine! I figured out a solution to my problem :)